# How to get the real final redirected URL using PHP or cURL?

Tags: php, curl

I know the `CURLINFO_EFFECTIVE_URL` of `curl_getinfo()` function can get the final redirected URL.

But when I tried the URL like 'http://google.com' or 'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Redirection' using cURL and tried to get the `CURLINFO_EFFECTIVE_URL`, it still returned the original URL ('http://google.com' and 'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Redirection'), not the real redirected URL ('https://www.google.com' or 'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Redirect'). (Each of their HTTP Status Code is 307 and 304)

In browsers, if I type 'http://google.com' and 'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Redirection', it'll automatically redirect into 'https://www.google.com' and 'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Redirect'.

Why `CURLINFO_EFFECTIVE_URL` didn't work here? And how can I get the final redirected URL?

**EDIT**

Here is my PHP code of cURL:

```
<?php
$url = "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Redirection";
$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);

$data = curl_exec($ch);
$redirected_url = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_EFFECTIVE_URL);
curl_close($ch);

echo $redirected_url;    //It should show the redirected URL.
?>
```

And I use 5.4.3 as my PHP version. Is there any wrong?

Comment: Did you set `CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION` aswell?

Comment: Yes, I have set `CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION` to `1`, but still the same...

Comment: It's worth noting that `https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Redirection` doesn't redirect anywhere for me in chrome either - it's directly a HTTP 200.